# Не приходят атрибуты запроса в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Начал изучать сервлеты и JSP, столкнулся с проблемой: в JSP не доходят запросы:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    ArrayList users = new ArrayList();
    try {
        EasyDB db = connectDB("postgres", "wasd123wasd5" , "javaTest");
        users = db.MakeQuerry("SELECT \"Name\", \"Password\", \"ID\", \"FullName\"\n" +
                "  FROM \"Users\";\n");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    request.setAttribute("users", users);
    System.out.println(users);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

Это сервлет, в него я передаю переменную `users`, это `ArrayList`, и я знаю, что `users !=null`, однако в JSP ничего не приходит:

```
<% out.print(request.getAttribute("users")); %>
```

этот код пишет `null`, я уже сто раз проверял, вдруг `users` все же равно `null`, но и в консоль и при всех остальных способах проверки `users` все - таки что-то равно именно тому что мне нужно, помогите, что делать? Все как в примерах в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

попбробуй поменять

```
request.setAttribute("users", users);
```

на

```
response.setAttribute("users", users);
```

Comment: При чем тут это? У response вообще нет метода setAttribute, вы можете посмотреть интернет, во всех примерах работает именно так

Comment: передавайте через параметры - setParameter(), getParameter()

Comment: @NEStenerusnester да сорри, посмотрел твой код он в общем выглядит правильным, можешь закинуть код на гитхаб свой проект? попробую проверить у себя.

Comment: https://github.com/artur1214/BusProject

Comment: интересно, я создал новый servlet и новый jsp и повесил новый сервлет на url `/abc` в него все приходит отлично, однако на старый который висит на стандартной ссылке `/` почему-то ничего не приходит, не объясните?

Comment: могу предположить что request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp") должно быть request.getRequestDispatcher("/")